# Animation is slow on iOS Device and fast in Unity editor?

Tags: c#, unity

I had made a Settings popup in the game and animated it like scale animation (from 0 to 1) values.
It is appearing very smooth and works good in the unity Editor, but after building to the device it appears laggy and jerky.

I have also changed `targetFrameRate` to `60` but it does not works.
My Game is running at 60 fps but why my animation is running slow and jerky on Device?

Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong..

Here is my Code:

```
public void ShowSettings()
{

    settingsAnim.SetBool ("isHidden",false);

}
public void CloseSettings()
{

    settingsAnim.SetBool ("isHidden",true);
}
```